# Contract violation error on insertion into binary search tree

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to insert an item into a binary search tree, but I'm getting an error and I can't understand why.
If I try to run:

```
(insert 11 '(5 '() '()))
```

The error is:

```
. . >: contract violation
  expected: real?
  given: quote
  argument position: 2nd
  other arguments...:
   11
```

Main code:

```
(define (node tree)
    (car tree))

(define (right-branch tree)
    (caddr tree))

(define (left-branch tree)
    (cadr tree))

(define (make-tree node left-branch right-branch)
    (list node left-branch right-branch))

(define (insert e tree)
    (cond((null? tree) (make-tree e '() '()))           
        ((> e (node tree))(make-tree (node tree) (left-branch tree) (insert e (right-branch tree)))) 
        ((< e (node tree))(make-tree (node tree) (insert e (left-branch tree)) (right-branch tree)))))
```

The error specifically points out (> e (node tree)) as the problematic piece of code.
Does anyone know what's happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You double quoted, try

```
(insert 11 '(5 () ()))
```

Comment: It's the habit of quoting the empty list... you're welcome ;-)